# How to get IMSI Number in Android SDK API Level 29 or higher?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I notice that when using Android 10/Q device, I am not able to get the IMSI Number using `TelephonyManager`,

```
TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String imsiNo = tel.getSubscriberId();
```

i will always get empty value for the imsiNo variable, but in Android SDK API level 28 or lower, it will always return the imsi value.

I have ensure to enable the READ_PHONE_STATE permission, but in Android 10/Q it will not able to get imsi number. Is there anyway to get IMSI number in Android 10/Q or higher version?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to get IMSI in android > Q

```
private String getImsiFromSubscriptionManager() {
    String simSerialNo = "";
    try {
        SubscriptionManager subsManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            List<SubscriptionInfo> subsList = subsManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

            if (subsList != null) {
                for (SubscriptionInfo subsInfo : subsList) {
                    if (subsInfo != null) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                            simSerialNo = subsInfo.getMccString() + subsInfo.getMncString() + subsInfo.getIccId().substring(8, 18);
                        }
                        Utility.DEBUG_LOG(TAG,"imsiNumber:"+simSerialNo);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                simSerialNo = "WiFi";
                Utility.DEBUG_LOG(TAG,"imsiNumber:"+simSerialNo);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(simSerialNo.isEmpty())
        simSerialNo = "N/A";

    return simSerialNo;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't, only system or device owner apps can read unique identifiers